# classpath error when using "Clean and Build Project" in NetBeans 12 with Maven and Java 14

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, classpath

When I try to "Clean and Build Project" in NetBeans I get the following error:

```
cd C:\Users\<user name>\Documents\NetBeansProjects\secondGUI; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-14.0.2" cmd /c "\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.0\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.0\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean install"

Error: -classpath requires class path specification
```

As best I can tell the problem is coming from Maven. When I run Maven at the command line (`mvn -version`) I get exactly the same error (`"Error: -classpath requires class path specification"`)

I am running in Windows 10. I have set the system environment variables as follows:

```
CLASSPATH C:\Users\<user name>\Documents\NetBeansProjects\
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2
M2_HOME C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.0\netbeans\java\maven
MAVEN_HOME C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.0\netbeans\java\maven
```

I can run `java --version` at the command line and get:

```
java 14.0.2 2020-07-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I can't run Maven from the command line because I get the classpath error as noted above.

I am just setting up all of this for the first time on this machine, so I expect that I have missed a piece of the puzzle some place. I am just not sure which piece it is or how to fix it. I am also not experienced in developing in this environment. So my question is how can/should I set up the class path either at the project level or at the system level to resolve this error. I would like to set it up so that it takes advantage of the integration of Maven into Netbeans. I'm not sure if it's helpful, but I did not install Maven separately. It was installed as part of the NetBeans installation.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide for resolving this error.

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: That `CLASSPATH` environment variable looks suspicious. I would remove it (it should not be set at the environment-level, anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the observation, andrewjames. I agree that it should not be set at the environment level. When I did that I was out of other options and was grasping at straws. Hopefully someone knows a more definitive answer that I can use to fix the entire situation. Anyway, thanks for the response.